# IOException: Cannot open socket using DNS

Tags: sockets, java-me, ioexception

When trying to open a socket using the example given in the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/io/SocketConnection.html):

```
try {
    SocketConnection sc = (SocketConnection)
            Connector.open("socket://host.com:79");
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I am getting an exception, here is the full stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot open socket using DNS
at java.lang.Throwable.fillInStackTrace(Throwable.java:122)
at java.lang.Throwable.<init>(Throwable.java:53)
at java.lang.Exception.<init>(Exception.java:20)
at java.io.IOException.<init>(IOException.java:23)
at ej.ecom.connection.socket.SocketConnectionImpl.openSocket(SocketConnectionImpl.java:206)
at ej.ecom.connection.socket.SocketConnectionImpl.open(SocketConnectionImpl.java:72)
at ej.ecom.connection.socket.ConnectionFactory.open(ConnectionFactory.java:32)
at ej.ecom.io.Connector.open(Connector.java:129)
at ej.ecom.io.Connector.open(Connector.java:93)
at fr.cameon.net.http.client.HTTPClientTest.main(HTTPClientTest.java:16)
```

I have tried using other ports and IPs but nothing seems to work. I haven't found anyone getting this exception description.

Comment: what ports and IPs have you tried?  the only one you show is a bogus hostname.

Comment: The problem is i don't know if i have to create a server first. Or is it supposed to connect to any existing host on the port 80?

Comment: You can **either** create your own server, to listen for socket connections, or connect to a hostname and port combination *that you know is already listening*.  For example, `www.google.com` and port `80`.  But, you can't connect to a hostname and port if there is nothing listening at that *endpoint*.

Comment: When I try with www.google.com and port 80 I get the same exception: Cannot open socket using DNS

Answer (score 0):

That's just an example code. You need to have valid server. Replace "socket://host.com:79" with your server